# react-apollo 3.x migration path for MutationProps?

Tags: typescript, react-apollo

I have a project I'm migrating from react-apollo 2.x -> 3.x. The 2.x codebase has this line:

```js
import { MutationProps } from 'react-apollo';
```

When I upgrade my dependencies to 3.x I get an error saying `node_modules/react-apollo/lib has no exported member 'MutationProps'`.

What is the migration path for `MutationProps` in 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no clear equivalent to that type in 3.x. I went with `MutationComponentOptions`, since it contained the specific attributes I needed.